# How to Create a Toy Example of the Curds and Whey Algorithm?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation, multivariate-analysis, regularization

Why is my simulated example failing?

I am trying to create a toy example of the [Curds and Whey](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/curds-whey-justtext.pdf) method for multivariate linear regression in python (An example in R would be very helpful as well).

I am inspired by the simulated example in [this article](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3183&context=etd) by John Kidd (Described on pages 11 and 12). However, I am not getting the advertised improvement over OLS.

```py
#Generating predictor matrix X
n = 100
p = 6
q = 5
R = p/n
X = np.random.randn(n,p)
#Generating coefficients that multiply X to create Y
coefs = np.random.randn(p,q)
#creating Y
Y = X @ coefs
#Creating dependence in Y by ensuring dependence in errors
r = .70
covariance = np.array([[r**0, r**1, r**2, r**3, r**4],
                       [r**1, r**0, r**1, r**2, r**3,],
                       [r**2, r**1, r**0, r**1, r**2,],
                       [r**3, r**2, r**1, r**0, r**1,],
                       [r**4, r**3, r**2, r**1, r**0]])
errors = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(5),
                                         cov=covariance, 
                                      size = n)
#adding correlated errors to Y
Y = Y + errors*10

ols = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)
ols_predictions = ols.predict(X)
np.sum(((Y - ols_predictions)**2)**(.5))
```

This OLS example above outputs an an root MSE of: 219.08

When I perform the Curds and Whey Algorithm

```py
#Standardizing X and Y
X_tranformer = StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = X_tranformer.transform(X)
Y_tranformer = StandardScaler().fit(Y)
Y_scaled = Y_tranformer.transform(Y)

#Computing CCA
cca = CCA(n_components=q)
cca.fit(X_scaled, Y_scaled)
X_c, Y_c = cca.transform(X_scaled, Y_scaled)
cs = np.corrcoef(X_c.T, Y_c.T).diagonal(offset=q)
T = cca.y_rotations_


#Computing Diagonal Shrinkage
denom_1 = (cs**2)*((1 - R)**2)
denom_2 = (1 - cs**2)*(R**2)
numer = (1 - R)*(cs**2 - R)
ds = numer/(denom_1 + denom_2)
ds[ds < 0] = 0
D = np.diag(ds)

#Predicting values
ols_cw = LinearRegression().fit(X_scaled, Y_scaled)
Y_c_predictions = ols_cw.predict(X_scaled)
cw_predictions = Y_tranformer.inverse_transform(Y_c_predictions @ T @ D @ np.linalg.inv(T))
np.sum(((Y - cw_predictions)**2))**(.5)
```

This outputs 221.68

I am not sure why my toy example is failing. I have tried computing T in a variety ways but the results are the same. Could anyone point me to an example in some statistical coding language that properly implements a toy example of this?

Comment: tip: If you have not yet done so, using np.random.seed() will start the random number generator at the same point each time for repeatable results during development. For example, "np.random.seed(5)" near the top of the code.

Comment: Thanks! That would definitely help this code black be more reproducible.